# How to convert a ByteIterable into a String?

Tags: java, xodus

When I put a key, I use `StringToEntry`:

```
store.put(txn, StringBinding.stringToEntry(key), StringBinding.stringToEntry(value));
```

and when I return it I get a ByteIterable:

```
ByteIterable result = store2.get(txn2, StringBinding.stringToEntry("bn:14271053n"));
```

How do I convert this into a String?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Bindings](https://github.com/JetBrains/xodus/wiki/Environments#bindings) section of Environments documentation says:

> All inheritors of the ComparableBinding class contain two static methods: one for getting the ByteIterable entry from a value, and another for getting value from an entry. For example, ByteBinding contains the following methods:

```
public static byte entryToByte(@NotNull final ByteIterable entry);

public static ArrayByteIterable byteToEntry(final byte object);
```

Similarly, `StringBinding` contains two methods as well, the desired method is

```
public static String entryToString(@NotNull final ByteIterable entry);
```